# Best way to implement basic SQL ordering

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm actually working in internship and I need to create a merchant website.
I was thinking about how to save orders.

At the moment I basically have :

```
user ( id, name, address, mail, password )
product ( id, name, description, vat, price )
```

I do believe that I have to make a reference to the user in my order, and I think that I would have done that :

```
order ( id, #user.id, price, date )
product_order ( #order.id, #product.id, qty )
```

Do you think  there is any better possibility ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have two tables for the order.

Create only one that has foreign keys to userid and productid.

For example:

```
**Order**
OrderId | UserId | ProductId | Price | Quantity | Date
```

Comment: I mean, one order contains mutliples products and the quantity is linked with the product will that still work ?

Comment: Oops...you are right...this won't work. Then your solution is fine...perhaps it is better to have the price column in product_order table and store the price for each product

Comment: I was thinking the same way but since we can retrieve that data with product_id i don't know which is best

Comment: It's more from "statistics" reasons i would say. Think of a case when you order something today and tomorrow you change the price. Also in order table you need status column too.